# Post-build commits: good or bad?

Tags: mercurial, post-build-event, post-build

Is it a good policy to automate source control commits following successful builds?

---

**Edit:** I'm asking because I want more frequent, incremental commits between versions that make it easier to find the point where a bug was introduced than rolling back 2K+ new lines of code between v1.0 and v1.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A successful build does not imply a successful code change. Do you never test your code? IF you had some sort of automated unit testing, I could understand the question (although I would still recommend against it - I would not consider a code change tested until you verified its functionality yourself). But an automated commit after a successful build - not if you like your team mates, or if they have access to weapons.

Comment: What if I'm using a DCVS and I'm only committing locally and reserve pushes to a central repo for manual action?

Comment: Sure, but personally, I still like to only commit code that I know works. That makes it a lot easier when you track a bug down. Let's say you committed code that compiles nicely but crashes spectacularly once you run it. Time to track down the bug - a great way do that is to diff against what's in the depot. Unfortunately, you had 5 successful compiles recently, which means 5 commits, and you don't know or remember when the code worked the last time. So have fun wasting time trying to find the version that worked, and then diff against it.

Comment: Also agree. It's not a tool's job to commit, it's a developer's job. Once you have compiled and tested (in your context) your change, even small, even incomplete, you can commit and push. The sooner you do that, the best it is (see the "Continuous Integration" article by Martin Fowler). This is not to say that _post_ commit automated builds are useless though. Using something like buildbot or hudson, you can test your changeset in different context/OS/usage etc. and discover integration problems earlier. Cheers, Christophe.

Answer (score 4):

No. Where would the meaningful commit messages come from? And the references to issue tracker items? How is the automated process supposed to know that a particular bit of work is complete?

With such a process in place, your repository would degrade to a glorified IDE undo buffer.

Comment: +1 for commit messages. Cannot emphasize the importance of clear and meaningful commit messages enough.